# How to set UITableViewCell corner radious for top and bottom cell (not for all the cell) in swift

Tags: ios, swift5, xcode12

Can you please let me know, how to add corner radious for custom UITableViewCell for top and bottom cell and not for all the cell. pls find the design screen for reference.
[image: c]

Answer (score 1):

Set your table view style to `.insetGrouped`, available since iOS 13.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code snippet for rounded corners.

```
if indexPath.row == 0
            {
                cell.baseView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                cell.baseView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
               
            }

            if indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1
            {
                cell.baseView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                cell.baseView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
                
            }
```